# Laravel Forge - Connect to Amazon

Tags: amazon-web-services, laravel-forge

So today i wanted to set up an integration Server. 
We are building a PHP Application using Laravel 5.5 and want to host it on AWS. 
We have also registered to Laravel Forge and Laravel Envoyer.

So for the start i wanted to connect my Laravel Forge account to Amazon. 
I signed into my amazon account, activated everything and created a new IAM User with AdministratorAccess Permission. I've saved everything and created the AWS secret and key. It is shown with status Active in the console.

Ok I headed over to Laravel Forge and went to Server Providers. I selected Amazon. in Profile Name i've entered the name of the user plus his key and secret. I thought i'd be done but i am getting this error:

Whoops! There were some problems with your input.

Invalid API credentials.

Anyone know how i can connect my forge with AWS or can point me to what i did wrong? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

This issue was happening with me as the AWS account wasn't properly activated. Please follow up with AWS in this regards!

Comment: i was able to connect now with AWS. The AWS account wasnt properly activated. you should check that.

But i cant create a server in any region. getting new error then :)

Comment: Yes. It seems to be case with mine as well. Thanks!

Comment: Spoken now with AWS support on the phone. They said its going to take some days until they solve some limitations on the account. 
So we will give them 2 next days otherwise we are looking for a new provider

Comment: Thanks mine was sorted as well.

Answer (score 0):

Having the same issue. I seem to be able to create servers in the US regions but nowhere else. Same error as the above. The JS console shows 500 server errors when selecting any other region. Hoping someone has found a solution to this.

I contacted Laravel Forge support and the only advise I got was about contacting AWS directly. Is quite frustrating.

Comment: yep same here too! contacted aws support and seems like i need to uprade the limits for servers in a specific region.

So imagine each region has a counter server -> user. 
And i bet for start each counter is set to 0. 
So you have to contat AWS to increase that limits so you can create servers on aws, which is a quite shitty schema.

Comment: Hmm can this be done on free accounts? This is an awful experience :(

Comment: i dont think so, we needed to upgrade to developer support plan to open up a ticket.